# Create array of arrays from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery

I am receiving after an ajax call the following as `response` using in php `json_encode`:

```
"['2013-02-24', 0]", "['2013-02-25', 0]", "['2013-02-26', 1]", "['2013-02-27', 6]", "['2013-02-28', 6]", "['2013-03-01', 3]", ...
```

How can I make in JavaScript from this an array of arrays? Is this even possible? I mean, I've tried with jQuery `makeArray` or with `parseJSON` with no success. What is the most preferred method?

Edit:

```
function submitForm(t) {
    $.ajax({type:'GET', url: 'charts.php', data:$(page_id).serialize(), success:
        function(response) {
            var myFanRemovesData = new Array(response);
            var myChart = new JSChart(chart_id, 'line');
            myChart.setDataArray(myFanRemovesData);
```

I have to use the array of arrays to set `myFanRemovesData` with it

Comment: This does not looks like valid JSON String

Comment: What's the type of the response ...?? string or JSON...??

Comment: using `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(response));` I receive the following: `[object String]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) strip out the double-quotes (`"`):

```
var json = json.replace(/"/g, '');
```

2) wrap the whole thing in square brackets:

```
json = "[" + json + "]";
```

3) replace the single-quotes with double-quotes (because the singles won't parse):

```
json = json.replace(/'/g, '"');
```

4) parse the json string:

```
var arrays = JSON.parse(json);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5ENs2/). It will alert the first date in the first array. (note: the data is pulled from the DIV to simulate the AJAX call and to avoid me having to mess around with escaping quote characters)

Comment: Who downvoted me by the way? I assume it was somebody who cannot write/type?

Comment: Wasn't me, but I don't think this is the way to go either. Instead, OP should fix his PHP script output to generate valid JSON.

Comment: @Bergi: Of course, you are right. But I can only answer the question, I would suggest a better way but I don't know enough about how OP server is creating the output data. I also don't do PHP

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var response = ["['2013-02-24', 0]", "['2013-02-25', 0]", "['2013-02-26', 1]"];
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var cleaned = response[i].replace(/'/g, "\"");
    response[i] = $.parseJSON(cleaned);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hu3Eu/

After this code, the `response` array will contain arrays, made out of the original strings.

Comment: This is a wonderful example but i have an issue: the `response` being a string if I use for example `$.makeArray(response)` I get something like that: `[""['2013-02-24', 10]", "['2013-02-25', 17]", "['201…0', 4]", "['2013-04-21', 4]", .... "]` which create another issue: how I get rid of those two `"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just example.. because you haven't provide us with any code...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function( responde ) {
    $.each(responde, function(i, v){ 
      alert(v.0 + ' --- ' + v.1);
    });
});
```

If you receive and expecting json you directly can use it as array/object :)
If its array you have to make a each loop so you can access each value..