# Convert JSON to array of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my output

```
[{"Phy_nm":"HCP-1","Brand_t":126.52,"Mkt_volume":181.23,"calls_recvd":7.94,"samples":30.86,"Avg":24.14}]
```

I tried doing this

```
var i = 0, result = [];

    while (i < data.length) {
        result.push([])
        for (var key in data[i].fields) {
            result[result.length - 1].push(data[i].fields[key])
        }
        i++
    }
```

How can I convert this to array of array in javascript like this

```
[
[{"Phy_nm":"HCP-1","Brand_t":126.52,"Mkt_volume":181.23,"calls_recvd":7.94,"samples":30.86,"Avg":24.14}]
]
```

Comment: so you want to add your json to an array

Comment: `var data = [{"Phy_nm":"HCP-1","Brand_t":126.52,"Mkt_volume":181.23,"calls_recvd":7.94,"samples":30.86,"Avg":24.14}]; var result = [data];`. This should do.

Comment: please add what is given and what you want to get.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @HassanImam and if you think you have a list of data then just do like this 

oldData.map(d){ result.push([d])}

Comment: Is it similar to this one: (create an array of arrays)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192925/create-array-of-arrays-from-json

Comment: @computer Mine is a valid Json hence I cannot parse this object..

Answer (score 0):

I dont get the logic tho...

since you are sure that your output will always be a valid JSON

```
var Output =[{"Phy_nm":"HCP-1","Brand_t":126.52,"Mkt_volume":181.23,"calls_recvd":7.94,"samples":30.86,"Avg":24.14}]
```

so the desired output would be this simple string trick

```
   var result = "[" + JSON.stringify(Output)  + "]";
```

Comment: No this will not create array of array, I trying to to do something like this Array[Array(1)]

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert that Json  to an array,in this case we simply do this.

```
var dataOutput =[{"Phy_nm":"HCP-1","Brand_t":126.52,"Mkt_volume":181.23,"calls_recvd":7.94,"samples":30.86,"Avg":24.14}]
var output=[dataOutput];
```

Comment: Yes this what I was expecting.., as Hassan Imam said!! Thanks for your help!!